# Getting a random colour when selecting a button in matching pairs game

Tags: java

I am creating the matching pairs game using buttons. When the buttons are clicked, they should have a different colour underneath them and there should be 8 different colours (as there is 16 buttons and 2 of the colours under the buttons would be the same). Currently, when I click on the buttons, they all just have the same colour underneath.

I've tried to set my function which sets the actual colour of the buttons to red just to test it, but it still didn't work. I've got a function called flip which acts like flipping a card over, so when it is called with the true value, the button should show the actual colour, and when it isn't called, the button .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this code:

```
public class ColorButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{
    Color actualColour;  // never assigned a value on object creation
    Color grey = new Color(128, 128, 128);
    Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);

    //...

    Color stateBack = grey;
    Color stateFront = actualColour;  // actualColour is null here
    Color stateFinished = black;

    // ....
```

In your test code the color that you're trying to change your button to, `stateFront` is null because it is assigned actualColour which is never initialized at the time of object creation, and so no color change occurs

Yes you may assign a valid Color object to actualColour, perhaps later, but stateFront remains null since its reference is never changed.

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense. I tried to set it using the ``setDrawColor`` and ``setActualColours`` methods however it didn't seem to work. From what I understand, the Main class is supposed to assign the different colours (although in this case it's only red for testing), then this is supposed to be passed onto the ``setDrawColor`` function which acts like a setter which will actually then set this. I think i've done this so i'm not quite sure where i've gone wrong, unless it's something different.

Comment: @Kappa123: The `setDrawColor(...)` method sets the actualColour field but does nothing for the stateFront field (as already stated in a round about way in my answer above).

Comment: Ahh I think I see what you're saying. So i'd need to initialize ``actualColour``variable to some colour so that it can then be changed?  I.e. if I do ``Colour actualColour = Color.BLUE`` and then call ``flip(true)`` in the ``actionPerformed`` method, all of the squares will be blue.